# how can i send an Email to a mailchimp list with mandrill and wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, email, mailchimp, mandrill

I have an account mailchimp where i have a list of subscribers.
I'm starting a plugin wordpress where i use the mandrill api.
I'm trying to get my the lists of mailchimp, and i'm trying to see how i can send with mandrill api an email (newsletter type) to the list mailchimp.

The thing is i can't find any code in the mandrill api for finding the lists or sending to a list.

I have installed the mailchimp plugin in wp to see what i can do with. and in it there is the mailchimp api that can get the lists.

But still with mandrill i can't find a way to send to a list.

In the documentation of mandrill is empty for me
https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/categories/200277227-API-Integration

as anyone an idea for me?
Thanks